# Adding websockets interface to standalone process

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, backgroundworker, asp.net-core

If I have a standalone process that runs continuously, is there a good method of adding an asp.net websocket interface to that such that I can send messages to interact with this process and also broadcast status updates?  Messages can be quite large and/or frequent.

This process doesn't need to be scheduled as it will be running as soon as the application starts.

I am asking because initially I thought I would just run an asp.net application that creates a thread on startup (in Startup.Configure I think?) but I've been reading that asp.net isn't designed for having background threads.  Using Windows Services is brought up but I am developing for Linux and OSX.

This is sort of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class Startup
{
    BackgroundServer server;

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // start server in another thread
        Task task = new Task( () => server.run(); );
        task.Start();

        app.Map("/ws", webSocketsApp =>
        {
            //  need this to enable websocket middleware!
            webSocketsApp.UseWebSockets(new WebSocketOptions() {ReplaceFeature = true, });

            webSocketsApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                    await Task.WhenAll([]{ProcessMessages(webSocket), ProcessSends(websocket)});
                    return;
                }
                await next();
            });
        });
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessages(WebSocket webSocket)
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            await server.sendMessage(websocket, message);
        }
        await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    private async Task ProcessSends(WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        while (!webSocket.isStateTerminal)
        {
            var message = await server.getMessage();
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(message), Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why WebSockets, of all things? Also, it's not ASP.NET itself that isn't designed for background threads - it's a more generic problem of hosted environments. Since you seem to have your own hosting environment (a custom executable), this doesn't apply. Only the usual multi-threading complications are relevant :) You might want to use `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ... }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)` instead of `new Task`, though.

Comment: We use WebSockets to allow our web based clients to interact with this process. One client can send a signal which would require sending updates to all other connected clients once that signal has been processed. Thank you for the LongRunning Task tip! In regards to ASP.NET not being designed for background threads, I've read about ASP.net instances being recycled for various reasons (low load, change in webconfig) which might disrupt background threads.

Comment: "Using Windows Services is brought up but I am developing for Linux and OSX." Yeah that sounds like the correct solution to me. So what exactly is the problem with running your service as a daemon?

Comment: @Voo What does the IPC look like in dotnet?  .net seems to have WCF but is that too heavyweight simply to add a websockets interface to a process? The webclients already expect a particular websockets protocol (not WCF's)  I could use sockets between the server process and asp.net server but then I'd be replicating a lot of what asp.net does. I was hoping for something like golang's easily embeddable websockets.

Comment: That code looks fine.